# How to print contents of named tuple from PSUTIL

Tags: python, namedtuple, psutil

Trying to display psutil values thus:-

```
  for VM psutil.virtual_memory():
      print (VM)
```

This prints the values but not the names.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks DS & GR: I managed to list item by item using ._fields (why is it naughty?); but will go with ._asdict() method as more appealing. KDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import psutil
for k, v in psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict().items():
    print(k, v)
```

...prints:

```
total 16706494464
available 7661907968
percent 54.1
used 7520182272
free 2695786496
active 9574060032
inactive 3523575808
buffers 896020480
cached 5594505216
shared 1172226048
slab 464887808
```

Answer (score 1):

Just print it without iterating over it, for debugging and development purposes.  This looks like:

```
svmem(total=16521965568, available=12267257856, percent=25.8, used=3729342464, free=3388936192, active=5169664000, inactive=3971186688, buffers=954048512, cached=8449638400, shared=181248000, slab=3778879488)
```

It's a named tuple, not a dict, so you're not really supposed to iterate over the "keys".  However, there's a slightly naughty ._fields you could use if you really have your heart set on getting a tuple of attribute names.